# Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm getting a very strange error on my puppet manifests

> Syntax error at '{'; expected '}' at /home/host_home/Code/puppet-manifests/env/development/krux-modules/kpypi/manifests/init.pp:8 on node vagrant-ops.krxd.net

Here is what init.pp looks like:

```
class kpypi inherits kpypi::params {
    include kpypi::params
    include kapache2
    include Kbase::packages
    include kutil

    kapache2::vhost_config_entry { "$my_name":
        source => "puppet:///modules/${my_name}/${vhost_config_file}",
    }

    #Create our docroot for the kpypi vhost and put our files in it.
    file { "$vhost_docroot":
        ensure => directory,
        recurse => true,
        mode => 555,
        ownder => 'root',
        group => 'root',

    }

    file { "$htpasswd_file":
        ensure => file,
        source => "puppet:///modules/${my_name}/${htpasswd_file}",
    }

    kutil::s3sync { "$package_dir":
        source_bucket => "$s3_package_bucket",
        delete_removed => true,
        hour => '0',
        minute => '*',
    }

    kutil::s3sync { "$documentation_dir":
        source_bucket => "$s3_documentation_bucket",
        delete_removed => false,
        hour => '0',
        minute => '*',
    }

}
```

The other thing that I noticed is that my editor (Sublime Text) recognizes the `file` blocks as collapsable, but not the kapache2 call. Am I missing something here?

Note: I'm using puppet 2.7

Comment: Answering my own question: As noted by others, the problem is caused by the accidental capital in the class name in line 4.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by the OP, the class names are lowercase.

And in attempting to include the class with a capital latter, it confused Puppet's parser sufficiently that it failed to properly perform variable interpolation in the source declaration on line 8.

Comment: Yes, Puppet is definitely case-sensitive. This is elaborated in the [Puppet language guide](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#resources). "When you see an uppercase resource type, that’s always a reference. A lowercase version is a declaration."

Comment: Good point. In my humble little opinion, Puppet goes somewhat beyond case-sensitivity into the realm of case-annoying.